# How can i display multiple views with ModuleFrontController in PS 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

With my Module Front Controller, i need to initialize it to display a form (formulaire.tpl) that the customer has to fill. Then the controller processes the data posted from the form using methods defines in my model (Formulaire.php) and then i would like to make it display another view (recapitulatif.tpl) that displays a reminder of data sent, an add to cart button for example or the possibility to fill the form in again.
As i would like to implement it the MVC way, i don't want to create a new php page to redirect my customer to but i would like to display somehow this second template after processing the data. Is there any way to do so with the controller? Here below, you can find my code, it doesn't work and it displays my first template and below my second..

```
class FormulaireModuleDefaultModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public $ssl = true;
    private $done_traitement = false;
    public function postProcess()
    {

        //On vérifie le bouton submit du formulaire
        if(Tools::isSubmit('bouton'))
            {

                // On va commencer en premier par récupérer l'id customer avec la variable cookie
                // et vérifier que la personnes est bien loggée
                global $cookie;
                if(!isset($cookie->id_customer))
                    {
                        $message='Aucun client loggé';
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $errors=array();
                        $id_cart=$this->context->cart->id;
                        $customer=$cookie->id_customer;
                        //On récupère les valeurs du formulaire
                        $prix=Tools::getValue('resultat');
                        $titre='porte_test';
                        $desc='Largeur de passage de '.Tools::getValue('largeur_passage').' mm, hauteur de passage de '.Tools::getValue('hauteur_passage')
                            .' mm, hauteur de linteau de '.Tools::getValue('hauteur_linteau').' mm, ecoinçon gauche de '.Tools::getValue('ecoincon_gauche')
                            .' mm, ecoincon_droit de '.Tools::getValue('ecoincon_droit'). ' mm, motif en '.Tools::getValue('motif_porte').' et de couleur '
                            .Tools::getValue('couleur_porte');
                        //On va vérifier les champs obligatoires
                        //Les champs sont remplis, on va faire le traitement des données.
                        $idprod=Formulaire::creerProduct($titre,0,13,$prix,$desc, 'mod_100',$customer);
                        Formulaire::addProduitauPanier($idprod);
                       $this->done_traitement=true;
                    }
                //On envoie le message si il existe:
                if(isset($message))self::$smarty->assign('message',$message);
                if(isset($errors))self::$smarty->assign('erreurs',$errors);
            }

    }
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        if($this->done_traitement)
                $this->display(__FILE__,'recapitulatif.tpl');

    }


    public function init(){
        $this->display_column_left = false;
        $this->display_column_right = false;
        $this->page_name = 'Configurateur';
        parent::init();
        $this->setTemplate('formulaire.tpl');

    }


}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT :**

Ok sorry for the question. It just took me 2 minutes to figure it out after posting the question. I only needed to change:

```
$this->display(__FILE__,'recapitulatif.tpl');
```

by :

```
$this->setTemplate('recapitulatif.tpl');
```

And now it works. Sorry for the inconvenience !